# how to run batch commands in unix

Tags: command-line

I am using Supercomputer (unix based) for my study

I need to run many commands at this same in .sh format

I do this every time

```
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_01_800999.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_02_800999.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_04_800999.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_08_800999.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_16_800999.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_01_140239.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_02_140239.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_04_140239.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_08_140239.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_16_140239.sh
...
...
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_01_158220.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_02_158220.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_04_158220.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_08_158220.sh
am@tinaroo1:~/.../Codes> qsub 69sk_16_158220.sh
```

for 100 files i have to type 100 commands

is there any way I can make the 100 command in one shot?

Answer (score 1):

You can run them all using a loop

```
for script in 69sk*.sh; do
    qsub "$script"
done
```

Note that `qsub` will send the script to the background on its own and will return immediately. If you wish to run scripts without using that, you can directly fork them to the background using `&`:

```
for script in 69sk*.sh; do
    ./"$script" &
done
```

Note that the scheduler won't necessarily put every script on its own core if you do it like this. If you have 100 cores, it would take more work if you want each script to be locked to exactly one core.

Comment: Thanks it works :) is there any chance it run with order? currently it takes files in random order

Comment: @asmgx  This answer runs the scripts all at once, hence the reference to locking each script to a separate core, and *exactly* the same time. So *in order* has no meaning.

Comment: @asmgx  You type the whole list every time?? Just type them into a script file once, add a shebang, and make it executable. The posted snippet *without* the ampersand would run them in sorted order consecutively, but the order you run them in manually is different -- you prioritise the names by the last field first. Mainly, why do you manually run them *consecutively* on a supercomputer? Does each command launch a subshell?

Comment: `qsub` submits the batch  script to the cluster scheduler and returns immediately. Backgrounding the command doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @asmgx When you `qsub` many jobs, many of them will be running concurrently. If you need them to run in a specific order you will need to modify your submittal command to put in dependency between jobs. Easy to do in `slurm`. `PBS` has the equivalent that you can check with your admins on for the syntax.